# TextButton width size not same like text

Tags: flutter, dart

I want make the `TextButton` width size same as text. But, if I wrap the `TextButton` with `ListView`, the width size of `TextButton` will same as the screen. How to make `TextButton` width same as the text?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            tacButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget tacButton() {
  return TextButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text('Text Button'),
  );
}
```

[image: Example when running]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap `tacButton(),` with `Center` or `Align`.

like

```
 ListView(
          children: [
            Center(child: tacButton()),
            tacButton(),
             Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: tacButton(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks, this is work. But, this will make it to always center. How about moving it start or end?

Comment: you can use align in this case

Comment: Okay. Thanks for helping me.